# Odoo 10 - To verify email for a partner

Tags: python, odoo

**Here my function for to verify a email :**

```
# Vérifie que l'adresse mail du partner soit valide
    @api.onchange('email')
    def adressmailtoverify(self):

        for rec in self:

            address_to_verify = rec.email
            match = re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+"
                             "(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$", address_to_verify)
            if not match:
                raise ValidationError("Problème de synthaxe adresse mail, merci de modifier")
            else:
                pass
```

**Here my error :**

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 885, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/horanet/horanet_go/horanet_web/models/tool_field_dirty.py", line 59, in onchange
    res = super(ToolFieldDirty, self).onchange(values, field_name, field_onchange)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5494, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5392, in _onchange_eval
    method_res = method(self)
  File "/var/lib/odoo/projects/Odoo/parthenay_tpa_mediatheque/models/inherited_partner.py", line 127, in adressmailtoverify
    "(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$", address_to_verify)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 141, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I have this error when to clear a email.

My second concern is that even if my exception is thrown, my partner is registered. Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked what is being returned from `rec.email`

Comment: You need to check if `rec.email` is not empty

Comment: rec.email return a unicode string. Example : u'azerty@hotmail.fr'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the for line and use this instead:

```
for rec in self.filtered("email"):
```

The problem happens because values are `False` in Odoo, and you cannot apply a regex to a `bool`.

Comment: Thanks you. It's perfect